# May i know the reason of closing the question here

Tags: discussion

Someone, please tell me why [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/192084/75368) is closed. and is the closed question appeared on the screen for others or not? how to reopen it?

Comment: The question was closed for the reasons stated at the top of your question. Specifically, it needs clarification.  Go back to the question page ... here https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/192084/a-rare-case-in-academic-regarding-to-the-retraction-of-an-article . You should click the box labelled "Improve this question" and rewrite the question to make it clearer. Then  close the edits.

Comment: The comments on the other question should be a guide. It is hard to give any answer with so little information.

Comment: i am new to this platform, so i now checked why my two previous questions are deleted? does anyone else have access to the edit option?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia SE. You can always edit your questions, whether closed or deleted. Edited closed questions will be pushed in a review queue where users can decide whether it can be reopened or not. If you instead edit a deleted question, you can then flag it for moderator attention and we mods will decide if it’s worth undeleting it. In any case, please don’t push people to reopen your question, and first edit it to fit the site rules.

Comment: @CrimsonDark, thank you so much for the guidance. I just see here "details or clarity" and "edit the question" options. do you mean to reopen it by these options?

Comment: however, thank yo so much everyone.

Comment: I don't have the power to reopen your question! That is for people who have much more reputation that I do. Have a look at the comments from @Massimo_Ortolano above. He explains what you need to do. Remember, the people here are actually trying to help, not to punish you (!) ... but it isn't easy to help when they don't have enough information to give sensible advice.

Answer (score 10):

You want a specific answer to a situation for which you do not provide specific details.  Until you give specific facts, such as quoting correspondence with the publisher (rather than paraphrase or report hearsay), there is really nothing to be done.

Answer (score 9):

One major reason is that you haven't said why the paper was retracted, implying only that it was the supervisor's pressure. The normal reasons are plagiarism, lack of novelty, bad fit for a journal (though it would have been rejected initially for that), errors in the paper, etc.

Yes, others can see closed questions. We can't answer them, however, but can still comment.

The way to get the question reopened is to edit it so that it is possible to answer and not a rant and then flag it for the mods to deal with or just wait to see if you get votes to reopen.